# Flutter Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap., null)

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, maps, google-maps-markers

Creating custom Icon in Google Map in flutter shows error.

My pubspec.yaml file

```
assets:
  - assets/truck.png
```

My Code is:

```
void getCustomIcon() async {
    customIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(
          devicePixelRatio: 2.5,
    ),
    'assets/truck.png');
}
```

Error is:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap., null)
E/flutter (15757): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter (15757): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
```

Comment: have you configured pubspec for assets. I think you are missing configuration

Comment: @Dev i added that image in assets folder and mentioned in pubspec file also brother.

Comment: what is the code for create marker where it is used

Comment: @Dev i added my code for creating marker in my question and i called that method in initstate of my class

Comment: Some time it works if you close the IDE/VS code and run again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

define in stateclass

```
BitmapDescriptor customIcon ;
```

call in `initState`

```
getBytesFromAsset('assets/truck.png', 64).then((onValue) {
      customIcon =BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(onValue);

    });
```

where function is

```
  static Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int width) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(), targetWidth: width);
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png)).buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

then in marker creation

```
markers.add(
            Marker(
                markerId: ....,
                position: ....,
                icon: customIcon ,
                 onTap: () { 
                  ....

                }
            )

        );
```

Comment: Probably it is better to convert the image to bmp offline. Image clients converting an image all the time...

Comment: @giorgio79 The problem I faced while converting png to bmp online was that they compulsorily filled the transparent background area with a solid colour. The above solution worked fine.

Comment: Where does `ui` come from? Please always try to provide full solutions. Besides, this code was copied from here https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/38474402.html

Comment: Add `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`

Comment: this doesn't work anymore

Comment: this is the laziest answer i ever found. please provide everything completely so people can follow properly. is it funny to keep people asking?