# Set image as marker

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on a Flutter app with Google Maps.

I'm trying to set an image as marker.
Everything is working but if I set a particular set of images, I get this error:

```
E/flutter ( 7241): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap., null, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.
```

Someone knows how to solve this issue?

I have this set for more than 500 images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60112985/7137608) we have the solution, it was a problem related to the method to get the image